404 not found when linking to imprint from footer
lib/layout/Footer.tsx
import Link from 'next/link'
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <footer className={wrapperClassname}>
      <div className="flex">
        <p className="text-xs">
            <Link href="/imprint/imprint" legacyBehavior>
                <a>Impressum</a>
            </Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  );
};

export default Footer;
lib/pages/imprint/imprint.tsx
export default function Imprint() {
    return <h1>Hello, Imprint!</h1>
}

I am getting 404 when clicking.
